# Access methods of Generic which extents a trait

Tags: scala, generics, traits

for getting a bit deeper into Scala I play around with a mysql wrapper. No production stuff, just experimenting.

I have a trait which specifies an abstract method:

```
trait EntityDefinition {
  def tableName: String
}
```

Then I have a parameterized class where I want to access tableName:

```
class FinagleRepository[T >: EntityDefinition] @Inject()(client: FinagleMysqlClient) {
  def create(entity: T): Future[Result] = {
    // Here it is impossible to call T.tableName
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're currently defining `EntityDefinition` to be a [lower bound](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/lower-type-bounds) for `T`, meaning `T` should be a *supertype* of `EntityDefinition`. What you actually want is for `EntityDefinition` to be a an [upper bound](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/upper-type-bounds.html) for `T`, meaning `T` to be a *subtype* of `EntityDefinition`:

```
class FinagleRepository[T <: EntityDefinition]
```

Comment: Hi Yuval, thanks for this answer. Such a silly mistake... :-)